# Why accessing 2d matrix in parfor so slow?

Tags: matlab, performance, parfor

Let's say I have a large matrix A:

```
A = rand(10000,10000);
```

The following serial code took around 0.5 seconds

```
tic
for i=1:5
    r=9999*rand(1);
    disp(A(round(r)+1, round(r)+1))
end
toc
```

Whereas the following code with parfor took around 47 seconds

```
tic
parfor i=1:5
    r=9999*rand(1);
    disp(A(round(r)+1, round(r)+1))
end
toc
```

How can I speed up the parfor code?

EDIT: If instead of using `disp`, I try to compute the sum with the following code

```
sum=0;
tic
for i=1:5000
   r=9999*rand(1);
   sum=sum+(A(round(r)+1, round(r)+1));
end
toc
```

This takes .025 sec

But `parfor` it takes 42.5 sec:

```
tic
parfor i=1:5000
   r=9999*rand(1);
   sum=sum+(A(round(r)+1, round(r)+1));
end
toc
```

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using? It might be relevant.

Comment: Matlab version 2018a

Comment: Most likely answer, it has to take the time to start up the parallel pool. Also, just in general, MATLAB's parallel toolbox is terrible.

Comment: the pool has already started up, so I don't think that's the reason

Comment: `disp` is a very bad function for testing. Regardless of how many core you have, they can only display on screen one at a time! Test using some numerical computation code to test parfor better. In essence, parfor does not accelerate everything, just code that is paralelizable. Displaying on screen is not.

Comment: If I compute the sum instead, `parfor` is still very slow. See the EDIT in the post

Comment: My answer still holds except for part 3

Comment: The `sum` loop is not parallelizable either. Each thread needs to write to the same variable.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is in not considering node communication overheads.

When you use a `parfor` to loop using parallel computation, you have to think about the structure of several worker nodes doing small tasks for the client node.

Here are some issues with the tests you present:

- The function `disp` is serial, since you can only display results one at a time to the client node. Communication between nodes is needed to schedule this task.
- Creating a summation external to the loop means all of the nodes have to communicate the current value back to the client node.
- `A` is a [broadcast variable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/broadcast-variable.html) in all of your examples. From the docs:

  > This type of variable can be useful or even essential for particular tasks. However, **large broadcast variables can cause significant communication between client and workers and increase parallel overhead**.

  The MATLAB editor warns you about this, underlining the variable in orange with the following tooltip:

  > The entire array or structure 'A' is a broadcast variable. This might result in unnecessary communication overhead.

---

Instead, we can calculate some random indices up front and slice `A` into temporary variables to use in the loop. Then do gathering operations (like summing all of the parts) after the loop.

```
k = 50;
sumA = zeros( k, 1 );         % Output values for each loop index
idx = randi( [1,1e4], k, 1 ); % Calculate our indices outside the loop
randA = A( idx, idx );        % Slice A outside the loop
parfor ii = 1:k
    sumA( ii ) = randA( ii ); % All that's left to do in the loop
end
sumA = sum( sumA );           % Collate results from all nodes
```

I did a quick benchmark to compare your 2 summation tests with the above code, using R2017b and 12 workers, here are my results:

```
               Serial loop: ~ 0.001 secs      
Parallel with broadcasting: ~ 100   secs
  Parallel no broadcasting: ~ 0.1   secs
```

Parallel loops are overkill for this operation, the overhead isn't justified, but it's clear that with some pre-allocation and avoiding of broadcast variables, they are at least not 5 orders of magnitude slower!

See how the version of the code without broadcast variables uses more vectorisation too, which will speed up the code without even having to use `parfor`. Optimising your code before using parallel computation will not only speed things up for serial computation, but often make the transition easier too!

---

Side note: `sum` and `i` are bad variable names because they are the names of built-in functions.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer! Everything boils down to: know what you are doing when using parallel code. Sending copies of the matrix to each worker is slow, and being them this big, possibly they are not even sent to the local workers cache, they are all in global RAM, so even slower to access them.

Answer (score -1):

So there are a few main causes,

1. MATLAB parallel toolbox sucks. It just does unless you're using the GPU portion.
2. The only time it's beneficial is if the individual tasks are large enough. Your computer has to dedicate a core to assigning jobs to all the other cores. This is expensive and has a lot of overhead unless the jobs are of sufficient size. Your computer is running overtime assigning small jobs. If you were assigning jobs that would each take a minute it would be a different story.
3. You're running too few jobs. You're only looping through 5 times on very small jobs. Why would you even bother trying to multithread this? When I assign it to loop through 500,000 times it finally gains a speedup with parfor if I reduce the matrix size to 1000 x 1000
4. When you run parfor, MATLAB has to duplicate memory across all of the treads, you have a 10,000 x 10,000 matrix which takes up 800 MB. Duplicated across a 4 core machine is 3,200 MB or probably half of your RAM. Operating on these arrays costs extra memory, potentially doubling the size -> 6,400 MB. Probably more than you can afford to use.

Simply put, "how do you I speed up this parfor code?"

You don't

Comment: My bet the main issue of OPs code is that `disp` is a serial job, and only one core at a time can do it, regrathless of the amount of cores one has.

Comment: And MATLAB's parallel toolbox works quite well when you know what you are doing ;)

Comment: I know it does, it's just if I'm going to put in the effort to get the parallelism, I'd rather just use my GPU ( :

Comment: I was just posting a simple example. My actual code loops through more times on much larger jobs

Comment: In that case, can you post an example with the approximate computational load and memory you are using?